# How to stop watching events (web3j)

Tags: web3j

I am using the following code to listen/watch contract events(web3j):

```
Event TRANSFER_EVENT = new Event("Transfer", Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true){}, new TypeReference<Address>(true){}, new TypeReference<Uint256>(false){}));
String TRANSFER_EVENT_HASH = EventEncoder.encode(TRANSFER_EVENT);

EthFilter filterProxy = new EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, contractAddress);  
filterProxy.addSingleTopic(TRANSFER_EVENT_HASH);

Disposable subscription = web3j.ethLogFlowable(filterProxy).subscribe(log -> {
                // address indexed _arg1
                Address arg1 = (Address) FunctionReturnDecoder.decodeIndexedValue(log.getTopics().get(1), new TypeReference<Address>() {});
                // bytes32 indexed _arg2
                Address arg2 = (Address) FunctionReturnDecoder.decodeIndexedValue(log.getTopics().get(2), new TypeReference<Address>() {});
                // uint8 _arg3
                Uint256 arg3 = (Uint256) FunctionReturnDecoder.decodeIndexedValue(log.getData(), new TypeReference<Uint256>() {});
                
        },Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

It's working fine and can capture all the events.

But how to stop the subscription? Tried subscription.dispose() and CountDownLatch, both doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution if unsubscribe does not work in the docs:

```
final Disposable disposable = events.subscribe(...)
disposable.dispose();
```

here is a link to where I found it: https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/getting_started/pub_sub/

Comment: There is no unsubscribe() method for this subscription.

Comment: I have edited my original answer, sorry I initially thought this was web3.js but I believe I found your answer which is the .dispose() function

Comment: dispose() also can't stop the subscription.